# Error when scaffolding identity in server side Blazor project

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a server-side Blazor application which was created with the "Individual User Accounts" option selected for Authentication.

I now want to customise the login page however when I select to add the Identity pages via scaffolding I receive the below error and I'm not sure where to start in terms of troubleshooting.

> Failed to compile the project in memory
>
> .OnInitializedAynsc() no suitable method found to overrirde

The above error is listed for each page within my project.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the `OnInitializedAsync` method from `EditAdministrator.razor.cs` file? don't need the whole code, but just the method definition.

Comment: It's server-side Blazor however as you'll see my problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your `EditAdministrator` class is not inheriting from `ComponentBase` and your `EditAdministrator.razor` should inherit from `EditAdministrator.razor.cs`

So an example code will be as below:

`EditAdministrator.razor` page class will have this on top:

```
@inherits EditAdministratorBase
```

And your `EditAdministrator.razor.cs` class:

```
public class EditAdministratorBase : ComponentBase
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The problem was indeed due to not inheriting from CompoenentBase.

Comment: Heads-up for anyone running into this problem in .NET5, your .razor file doesn't need to inherit from .razor.cs anymore, as long as the naming is the same, but you DO need to inherit from `ComponentBase `, even though the code runs fine if you don't.

Comment: This has no doubt saved me hours of head scratching - thanks!

Comment: Hello! I'm having this issue now, I did the `ComponentBase` items, but now it is failing on other Utilities I have with this error: \Hr\Hr.razor.cs (22,26) error CS 0103. The name 'hrCoreUtilities' does not exist in the current context. Any idea?

Comment: This is also required in .NET7.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I fixed a similar issue in my Blazor Server project by ensuring that no code defined in a `.cs` file *ever* called any public static methods/classes/enums defined in any `.razor` file. For whatever reason, that just fixed scaffolding for me. For me, all these errors were detailed in the error box.

The VS compiler will tolerate these calls but the ASP.NET code generator will not. At least not yet.

Comment: A workaround on a standard Blazor project with a Pages folder causing compilation issues:
- Temporarily exclude the "Pages" folder from the project.
- Check that the project can still be compiled without error.
- Scaffold the required identity items
- Include the "Pages" folder in the project